# Why git rebase overwrite my local changes? How to avoid overwrite?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm trying to rebase my branch with the master. But it is always overwrite my local changes after rebase.

I'm using the command `git rebase`  and it will show one file conflict, then I manually resolved the conflicts. 
After tried `git rebase --continue` . Then I found my local changes are missing.

How to preserve the local changes and rebase with a master?

Comment: Did you used any other command like `git stash`?

Comment: @Kaushal   I didn't stash. I have commit my all changes before rebase.

Comment: Did you *finish* the rebase? I think you're just getting confused by the state of an in-progress rebase.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your working directory was dirty at the time you did your rebase.  You should probably be prepared for your working directory and stage to be wiped when you do a rebase.  As a workaround, if you find yourself with a non empty working directory and/or stage, but you need to rebase to the latest other branch, you could do a stash, i.e.

```
git stash
```

Git will make 2 (or even 3) commits to preserve your working directory and stage as they currently are.  After the rebase is complete, you can get these changes back by applying the stash:

```
git stash apply
```

I think in some cases Git would not even allow you to do a merge or rebase depending on the state of your working directory and stage.  But in any case, it might be a good idea to make sure they are clean before rebasing.

Comment: As you note, git won't allow you to rebase when the working directory is dirty. It will output an error and abort the rebasing progress. I doubt this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First things don't forgot add & commit current files before taking rebase.

After conflict resolved in files manually. to mark as conflict resolved use **`git add <file>`** then `git rebase --continue`. then `git push`

so,steps are

1. git add
2. git commit
3. git rebase
4. if there is conflict solve conflict & to mark files conflict solved use `git add <file_name>`
5. git rebase --continue
6. git push

Answer (score 1):

Without much information about your current state, it's possible that some of your local commits might already be part of the branch you're rebasing onto.

For example, let's say you're trying to rebase `develop` on top of `master`. The `develop` branch contains a number of commits, but you've merged `develop` into `master` a few commits back.

In this case, `git rebase master` may appear to lose some of the commits, but git has detected they're already part of `master` so they don't need to be reapplied.

You can use `git rebase --interactive` to be presented with the list of commits that are about to be rebased. If you don't see some commits you expected, or you see more commits than you expected, you might need to look at using `--onto` to change the starting point for the rebased commits.

Answer (score 0):

Strange things will happen if you do something wrong in the face of conflicts:

**WRONG:**

```
$ editor path/to/conflicted/file # resolve conflicts in editor
$ git commit --amend # no!

$ editor path/to/conflicted/file # resolve conflicts in editor
$ git commit -a # no!
```

Follow the correct steps:

```
$ editor path/to/conflicted/file  # resolve conflicts in editor
$ git add path/to/conflicted/file # stage resolved file
$ git rebase --continue
```

You might be confused by interactive rebase workflow. When you interactively rebase and stop at some commit with `edit`, it looks similar to the conflict situation: a rebase has stopped partway through, and you can fix things and then `git rebase --continue`. But  in the interactive rebase `edit` case, the edited commit is fully applied, so you can `git commit --amend` it, or add new commits on top of it, after which the rebase will continue.

I got tripped up by this a few times in the past; I'm so used to interactive rebasing, from doing it frequently, that just from "muscle memory" I've done  silly things like `git commit --amend` after resolving conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I hope you are not directly working on the master branch in your local repo, and you have a separate branch to which you push your local changes. After the work is done on the branch, you can create a pull request or merge with the master branch.

Assuming you have a separate branch, follow these steps to rebase with master without losing your local changes. If you are in another branch other than master:

```
git checkout master
```

Then proceed with the following commands:

```
git remote -v
git remote add upstream https://github.com/url_of_the_repo_you_are_working_on
git pull upstream master
git checkout branch_name_you_are_working_on
git rebase -i master
```

At this point, your branch in your local repo will be updated, and your changes in your branch will be intact. Now you can push your changes to the remote branch:

```
git push -f origin branch_name_you_are_working_on
```

Comment: I checked  https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing    to do. Your steps are different. Then what about the steps here in the link? is it really overwriting the local changes when rebasing?

Comment: @everalian Hi, I went through the link, so they have discussed incorporating the new feature from master branch into the local repo - using merging and rebasing. I do not think either of these methods will rewrite your local changes. The difference is that, using the method I had mentioned, your master branch will not be updated - your feature branch will be updated with the new remote changes, and the changes will be there too. Using the approach mentioned there, your master branch in the local repo also gets updated.